# React-Native Headless task not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, connectycube

I'm using sample code available on connecty-cube GitHub repo. When I call to user who is on android phone doesn't receive the notification for call when app is in background. And when app is open user can see the incoming call. Constructor of PushNotificationsService run and I can see this console `[PushNotificationsService][constructor]`. But inside `_registerBackgroundTasks()` function `[JSNotifyWhenKilledTask] notificationBundle` console doesn't run. I do get UDID for channels **APNS, APNS VOIP** and UDID for channel **FCM** in connecty cube dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

So that's how I figured out the problem.

- Make sure you have properly configured each step of every required library for connecty-cube.
- [Follow the docs](https://developers.connectycube.com/reactnative/)
- After that I checked sdk version of firebase on firebase console.
  It stated `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'` in  `(<project>/build.gradle)`. But mine was `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'`. And because of that notification was not appearing. Now it's works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-reactnative-samples/tree/master/RNVideoChat

I suggest the following:

- follow Getting started guide https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-reactnative-samples/tree/master/RNVideoChat#getting-started and make sure you have `google-services.json` properly located
- Re-check https://developers.connectycube.com/reactnative/videocalling?id=receive-call-request-in-backgroundkilled-state where it describes how BG  task works